# How to solve "Higher version than referenced assembly" message

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, reference, dependencies

Am not experienced in `C` stacks, but am trying to build [this](https://github.com/yingzheng/mdcm-printscp) DICOM project, it seems it's depending on a 'no-longer' existing project, so I tried to compile [mdcm](https://github.com/fo-dicom/mdcm) instead to generate the DLLs.

the generated dlls produce `DICOM` and `Nlog`, NLog didn't seem to work with the target project, missing classes etc ... when I installed `Nlog version 1.0` using `Nuget package manager` the missing classes issues got solved but now I get the below error message.

what are possible solution to this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means a dependency references a version of a package that is greater than the one you have installed into your app but your app reference will "win" since it is a direct reference, hence the error.

To fix it, you should install/upgrade to version 2 of NLog directly into your app although there might be build/runtime issues with that depending on the changes made in v2.

Comment: I used an older version of mdcm which used `Nlog` version `1`